How to implement circuit breaker and retry policy in an express app
I have an express backend and i want to implement a circuit breaker and retry policy for each endpoint. I have explored a few libraries like polly.js and opossum but as far as i understand polly.js only allows implementing retry policies and opossum only allows implementing circuit breaking. Please correct me if im wrong with above statements since their documentation isn’t very good.
For anyone answering please provide a code snippet for any dummy endpoint.

It would help if you posted a code example of what you've tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

@SamDean i think i was pretty clear mentioning that i needed help from someone telling me how to achieve circuit breaking and retry in an express app and not “correct/help with my existing code”. Please try to understand the problem before downvoting next time.

There was a while ago when I used NodeJs but that time we used cockatiel as our resilience library. I'm not sure how neatly integrates with expressjs but I think it worths a try.

Hey @PeterCsala thanks for the suggestion. I explored it and it seems like it can work with express. Thanks for the suggestion i will try it and let you know.

Hey @PeterCsala thanks again, cockatiel works, please post this as the answer i will mark it resolved asap since some people are downvoting genuine questions on this platform just cause they dont know the answer.

@JayendraAwasthi I'm happy that cockatiel worked for you. IMHO if you could post a simple example code where you decorate an API endpoint with resiliency policies that would be more beneficial for the community than my library link post.

@PeterCsala sure thanks for the suggestion. Will do it in a bit.

@JayendraAwasthi Are you planning to post a sample code?

@PeterCsala forgot about it. Will do it today

As @PeterCsala mentioned, we can use cockatiel in an express app to implement retry and circuit breaker policies.
For this purpose I made a policy wrapper file as below:
import {
    ConsecutiveBreaker,
    ExponentialBackoff,
    retry,
    handleAll,
    circuitBreaker,
    wrap,
} from 'cockatiel';

// Create a retry policy that'll try whatever function we execute 3
// times with a randomized exponential backoff.
const retryPolicy = retry(handleAll, {
    maxAttempts: 3,
    backoff: new ExponentialBackoff(),
});

// Create a circuit breaker that'll stop calling the executed function for 10
// seconds if it fails 5 times in a row. This can give time for e.g. a database
// to recover without getting tons of traffic.
const circuitBreakerPolicy = circuitBreaker(handleAll, {
    halfOpenAfter: 10 * 1000,
    breaker: new ConsecutiveBreaker(5),
});

const combinedPolicy = wrap(retryPolicy, circuitBreakerPolicy);

retryPolicy.onRetry((context) => {
    console.log(`Retry on atempt #${context.attempt} after ${context.delay}ms`);
});

circuitBreakerPolicy.onBreak(() => {
    console.log('Circuit breaker open');
});
circuitBreakerPolicy.onHalfOpen(() => {
    console.log('Circuit breaker half open');
});

// combinedPolicy.onSuccess((error) => {
//     console.log('acceptable under the policy', error);
// });
combinedPolicy.onFailure((error) => {
    console.log('policy failed');
    console.log(error);
});

export default combinedPolicy;

Now, we can wrap any function in this wrapper to implement these policies on it like below:
await combinedPolicy.execute(() => functionWhichMightThrowError())

